# Windows Program Level Proxy

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, application

On Windows Server, I’m running same software using multiple Windows Accounts trying to access internet via different public IP addresses.

I’m tried VPN, but it created only single global connection only, any solutions to this?

Goal is to create different public IP for each running software instance, please guide if can be done via any server custom setup or through paid software.

Thanks.

Update:
Windows login multiple user accounts on same server, all can running same program, but VPN connection is global not user account based, facing issue cannot connect 1 user account with 1 VPN. VPN tried is using OpenVPN client. Thanks.

Comment: This question should apply to all program without own proxy setting. Which part of the question is not specific please left comment, not just put on hold & down vote without details please...

Comment: What does that matter? You need to explain your problem, reasoning and evironment a lot better.

Comment: Stop spamming my notifications. Read our [help] and [How to ask better questions on Serverfault](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608)